# Postgres work_mem tuning

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have 2 postgres instances in azure.

I see every hour:

1. 1 temporary file created in one postgres instance (About 8 MB Max
   Size)
2. 4 temporary files are created in another postgres instance
   (About 11 MB Max Size)

I thought this was frequent enough for me to increase work_mem...
I increased work_mem to 8MB and 12 MB respectively in the 2 postgres instances but then I saw the temporary files were still created..

This time I saw each instance has one temporary file of 16MB size each... this behavior confuses me..
I expected that temporary file creation would stop..

I tried to refer to: https://pganalyze.com/docs/log-insights/server/S7

Is few temporary files every hour not a big deal?
Should I not tune work_mem ?

Comment: What statement is creating the temp file? It looks like the page you linked is referring to work_mem instead of maintenance_work_mem (the last one is used at index creation). Have a look at the [postgresql wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server).

Comment: Postgres creates temp files when it has to do lot of sort/hash, join operations for the query workload that it is processing and if the configured work memory is not able to handle. Check the types of queries that your server is executing during the time it creates such temp files. If you have more memory and if PG is not configured to utilize it, you should increase ```work_mem``` setting, do some trials, there is no magic number. See this [article](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/06/12/configuring-work-mem-on-postgres/) for more background on properly setting this parameter.

Comment: Tuning the server depends on lot of factors like the memory, number of CPUs, type of disk, kind of queries and data workload and PG version and whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: Use `pg_stat_statements` to find the queries that create temp files. Then run those statements with different values of `work_mem` to see how much you'd need to get rid of the temp files. But a few temp files per hour are usually fine.